# PyQT4 testing installation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have just installed pyqt4 with python 2.7 but i'm not sure it's correctly installed.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
window.setWindowTitle("PyQT Tuts!")

window.show()
```

I receive:

```
NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined
```

How can I check it's been correctly installed, I used home-brew on Mac OS el capitan?

Comment: It is not possible to get that error message if the import statements did not fail. So the code you posted is not the code you are actually running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIP must be installed before building and using PyQt4.

You can get the latest release of the SIP source code from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download.